# How/where can i learn everything unity2d

Tags: unity, 2d, reinforcement-learning

I just learnt unity basics and would like to learn everything else related to 2d development beginner to advanced in less time.

Because i dont want to stick to game business/development for a long time.

Any websites if you know that has everything thats mentioned above?

Comment: I think Google can give you more authentic and good stuff regarding this. Well my advise to have a look on General Game Development or Computer Graphics concepts (that should include info about Camera,Coordinate system,Transformations,Interpolation/Extrapolation, Viewport/WorldWindow,Panning, Collision Detection etc) with all the mathematics behind all these, so you can easily work on any game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good start
http://unity3d.com/learn
http://forum.unity3d.com

Virtual Game Lab also have an updated list of resources and tutorials for learning Unity. 
http://www.virtualgamelab.com/unity-resources.html

My recommendation for you is to pick a couple of old school 2d games and try to remake them. This will make you face real game development problems.

Good luck